# Advanced pattern matching swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Is there way to use optionals in `switch-case` branches?
For example: some function `f(arg:)` returns `String?`.
We require to perform some `switch-case` branch when `f(arg:)` returns non‑nil value, and use this value. See the following example.

```
func f(arg: Int) -> String?

let someValue: Int = ...

switch someValue {
    case -3, -2, -1:
        print("error: negative")
    case 10, 11, 12:
        print("error: too big")
    case let value, let str = f(arg: value): // HOW ????
        print("success: non-nil string \(str)")
    default:
        print("fail")    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `switch` statement is equivalent to this:

```
switch someValue {
    case -3, -2, -1:
        print("error: negative")
    case 10, 11, 12:
        print("error: too big")
    default:
        if let str = f(arg: someValue) {
            print("success: non-nil string \(str)")
        } else {
            print("fail")
        }
}
```

But a cleaner way to write that would be using a `guard` statement so you know that `someValue` is valid before passing it to the function:

```
guard case 0...9 = someValue else {
    print("someValue is outside of valid range")
    // Handle error
    return
}

if let str = f(arg: someValue) {
    print("success: non-nil string \(str)")
} else {
    print("fail")
}
```

Another alternative is to simply make `f` returns `nil` if the argument is not in the expected range:

```
func f(arg: Int) -> String? {
    guard case 0...9 = arg else {
        print("\(arg) is not in the valid range of 0...9")
        return nil
    }

    // ...
}

if let str = f(arg: someValue) {
    print("success: non-nil string \(str)")
} else {
    print("fail")
}
```

Comment: using `case let value` is better than `default`. Then you can use `if let str = f(arg: value)`

Comment: Can you enlighten us why it is better? After you have caught all invalid values, only valid values are left in the `default` case

Comment: Yes, using `default` is also logically correct. But we could write better in Swift because of the following two facts for Swift programming

1. if developers use `default` in Swift `switch`, it indicates that the matching value is no longer useful. 

2. The smaller scope of the variable, the easier for others to trace.

for better naming we could use `case let validValue`

Comment: I don't see any advantage whatsoever in what you described. You are making the code more verbose for no good reason

Comment: You don't see the advantages doesn't means it not exist. You are making the code more imperative for no good reason. (others won't get any idea where is the `someValue` come from unless tracing from top to bottom / step by step)

Comment: I'll end this silly conversation as "let's agree to disagree"!

Answer (score 1):

Old one but this is probably what you want:

```
func f(arg: Int) -> String?

let someValue: Int = ...

switch (someValue, f(arg: value)) {
    case (-3 ... -1, _):
        print("error: negative")
    case (10...12, _):
        print("error: too big")
    case (_, let str?):
        print("success: non-nil string \(str)")
    default:
        print("fail")    
}
```